# AndroidAnnotations RestService https

Tags: android, android-annotations

I used AndroidAnnotations in my Android project, my app performs requests to server in http. Now i need to use SSL on my api server.
Is possible to perform requests to https server with AndroidAnnotations RestService?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Refer here https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Simple-HTTPS

Comment: I need to use Rest API (https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest%20API) with @Rest annotation, is it possible?

Comment: If that's the case then I would strongly suggest you to use retrofit. More info here http://square.github.io/retrofit/. In the website the example demonstrates the https connection and we are also using it in one of our application. It's really fast.

Comment: Actually just use `https` in the root url. If you want to accept certain certificates, you can inject a custom [requestfactory](https://github.com/yDelouis/selfoss-android/blob/517e68d3722751863062d643888ffaa8feb737aa/app/src/main/java/fr/ydelouis/selfoss/rest/SelfossApiRequestFactory.java) (this example accept all certs).